# PHP write as ANSI instead of UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, save, simplexml

I have to servers with Apache-PHP-MySQL. First is Linux, second is Windows.

The PHP script use simpleXML to save string as files XML using asXML(file_name). On Linux - saves all files in encoding UTF-8.
But on Windows depends - if there are characters with accents in string like òèà... - saves as ANSI, if no - saves as UTF-8.
Exists a parameter in php.ini or something else that can ensure that encoding of file is always UTF-8?
Thanks.

Comment: Why should this matter? The `encoding` attribute tells the parser how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_set_charset($this->connect,'utf8');
ensure that from db you receive in utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're actually adding the characters in ANSI. I doubt simplexml does automatic conversion of your characters.. so make sure you're already using valid UTF-8 strings beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

According to this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php#79258; SimpleXML will convert everything to UTF-8 no matter what.

If you want to change it, you may want to look into xml_parser_create() instead, but it only supports ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII and UTF-8 as source encodings.

http://php.net/manual/en/xml.encoding.php